# Question regarding compatibility of Java 8 C++ distribution libraries with JRE 17

Tags: java, windows, x86-64, upgrade

In our product we are working on upgrading Java from version 8 to 17 on Windows AMD64.
In that upgrade once the deployment is done I notice the JRE folder is having C++ distributed libraries from Java 8 as those are having later versions than Java 17.

For example, library a.dll Java8 version is xx but Java17 is at
library ap-ms-win-crt-utility-l1-1-0.dll's version is 10.0.19041.685 at Java8 and for the same dll is at version 10.0.17763.132 in Java17.
Please note that Java 8 has a higher version than Java17.

Wondering if that later version of C++ distributed libraries is compatible in Java 17.
Can anybody shed some light on this.

Not a relevant section.

Comment: [Microsoft's article on the topic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/porting/binary-compat-2015-2017?view=msvc-170) if you're not confused enough yet